# Send celery tasks to a defined queue using celerybeat-mongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, celery, celerybeat

I am using `mongodb` to store my celery tasks and MongoScheduler to send them periodically, for this i am using github project `celerybeat-mongo` here is link https://github.com/zmap/celerybeat-mongo.

I followed examples present in GitHub and checked in `celerybeatmongo/scheduler.py line 30` that we can send tasks to different queues. I have created multiple queues and I am trying to send a task to a specific queue but tasks are not sent to the specified queue instead they are sent to queue name `celery`.

here is my django **settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
#CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('feeds', Exchange('feeds'), routing_key='long_tasks'),
)

CELERY_ROUTES = ({
    'A.tasks.A_tasks': {'queue': 'feeds', 'routing_key': 'long_tasks',},
    'B.tasks.B_tasks': {'queue': 'default', 'routing_key': 'default',},
    'C.tasks.C_tasks': {'queue': 'feeds', 'routing_key': 'long_tasks',},
    })
```

and in mongodb I have **schedules** (for task B)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cee650c53313c232c104089"),
    "_cls" : "PeriodicTask",
    "name" : "B",
    "task" : "B.tasks.B_tasks",
    "crontab" : {
        "_cls" : "Crontab",
        "minute" : "*/1",
        "hour" : "*",
        "day_of_week" : "*",
        "day_of_month" : "*",
        "month_of_year" : "*"
    },
    "args" : [],
    "kwargs" : {},
    "options" : {
        "queue" : "default",
        "exchange" : "default",
        "routing_key" : "default"
    },
    "enabled" : true,
    "total_run_count" : 2,
    "run_immediately" : false,
    "last_run_at" : ISODate("2019-05-30T06:29:41.568Z")
}
```

in my **terminal 1**

```
celery -A project worker -l info -Q default -c 2
```

in my **terminal 2**

```
celery -A project beat -S celerybeatmongo.schedulers.MongoScheduler -l info
```

**in redis-cli i have checked keys using `key *` but there is no queue name `default` and `feeds` but there is a queue named `celery`.**

please suggest me if i need changes in my settings or anywhere else to run this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the wrong field for setting the routes in celery conf so celery is falling back to the default queue name of "celery".
Try something like this instead in your config (note task_routes instead of celery_routes):

```
celery.conf.task_routes = {
    'a.*': {
        'queue': 'a_workers',
    },
    'b.*': {
        'queue': 'b_workers',
    },
}
```

I believe default task name in celery would be the full module path in python, for simlicitys sake I normally just give my tasks a hardcoded name with a prefix that I can later use for routing tasks the way I wish like so:

```
@celery.task(name='a.add')
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@celery.task(name='b.sub')
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y
```

I would then start different celery workers, passing the queue names like:

```
celery -A myproj.tasks.a worker --loglevel=info -Ofair -Q a_workers
celery -A myproj.tasks.b worker --loglevel=info -Ofair -Q b_workers
```